# SIMD Registers in ARM processor

Tags: neon

My question is about ARM NEON.

First question is about the register's size.
I'd like to know Apple A6's and Cortex A15's actual SIMD register size.

Second question is about the SIMD instruction's cycle.
I assume that lot of ARM processor's NEON register is 64bit.

The manual states: "As dual view, it's 128 bit wide".
Does this mean that even if I use 4 x 32bit value at 2 of 64 bit NEON registers, It'll be processed at one cycle?

I'd also like to know cycle count differences between 128 bit NEON and 64 bit NEON.

Comment: All this should be covered in excruciating detail in the CPU manuals, shouldn't it?  I mean, that's what a CPU manual is *for*.

Comment: cHao // Did you find Apple A6's Manual?

Comment: Nope.  I didn't look for it.  That's your job.  :)

Comment: First , I asked here because I couldn't find it, anything that related about Apple A6.

Comment: Second, Following question is about the cycle. I need some expert person's answer who has specify knowledge about processing cycle on NEONSIMD instruction.

Comment: Hence If I could find on just simple googling, I wouldn't ask here, that's why I'm asking people's answer here. Thank you for your concern btw @cHao :P

Comment: If there's no manual for the A6, then Apple doesn't want people knowing about its innards.  If that's the case, the only people here who would have access to resources other than the web and the ARM manuals...are almost certainly under an NDA that they're not going to risk breaking on a site they don't even get paid to answer questions on.  :P  What's on the web, is what there is.

Comment: Thank you, I may need to wait someone who know or who wondering about same topic. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the instruction executed.

As a general rule of thumb, simple ALU instructions require no more cycles dealing with Q registers than D registers, but multiply and/or permute instructions need twice the cycles when operating on Q registers. You should also be aware that very often the results in the lower 64-bits of Qd are available earlier than the ones in the upper half.

I don't think Apple's A6 behaves much differently than the "original" CA-15 when it comes to cycles.
And since they all share the very same ISA, you can be assured that the registers are the same within the ARMv7 architecture.